# React Native Navigation - Nested Navigator with Overlay

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm having a bit of a rough time figuring out how to structure my project. I have this MiniPlayer (see 2. pic) that I would like to overlay over all other screens whenever a song is playing. So far I solved it this way:

[image]

However, adding it like that I can't find a way to navigate from it to another screen since it's not part of any navigator. And I can't really add it to any of the navigators I have. If I add it to the TabsNav I get an additional tab that I don't want, if I add it to the stack, it's hidden when I open another tab. Can anyone give me a hint on how to move forward here or what I'm overlooking? Thanks a lot in advance :)

[image]

Comment: why you need to navigate from the player component to another screen " I can't find a way to navigate from it to another screen" ?

Comment: There are multiple ways to get to the AudioPlayer file. Since it's part of the normal navigation, that isn't an issue. Now as soon as a song is playing, the MiniPlayer thing turns visible. Now my goal would be that one could click onto the MiniPlayer (no matter where you are) and then it would redirect you to the AudioPlayer. But that doesn't work since the MiniPlayer isn't part of the navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way to implement this would be using the tabBar prop.
[link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbar)

Comment: Thanks for answering, Rohit. I had a quick look into that part of the docu, so far I'm not really sure how that applies to my problem, but I'll give it a more detailed look later.

Comment: Had a chance to look into it and this is exactly what I needed. It allows me to conditionally render a different TabBar depending on my needs. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: glad to help :)